# Cannot see chatter feed when a field is updated by ETL

Tags: chatter, etl, talend

I have enabled tracking on some fields of product table, and would like to receive a chatter feed when I follow a record and there is a change in those fields.
If I change manually the data I correctly receive a chatter feed, but if the change is done by the Talend ETL (with data from ERP) no feed is shown, although the field data is actually modified and the record last edite date is updated.
How can I get feeds for ETL updates?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Talend, but my best guess is that it's setting the `DisableFeedTrackingHeader` SOAP header to `true` when it updates records. Is there any way to configure Talend to set it to `false`? Here's the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_disablefeedtracking.htm) for the header.